# Is there any way not to use ApacheHttpClientFactory in Selenuim?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Want to test the preinstalled APK, like a `Caller` and `Calculator` on the real `Android` device using `Appium`. All the tutorials show that I need to use URL.

```
dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.43.242:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But the `ApacheHttpClient$Factory` is deprecated in `Selenium 3`. How to solve?

Tried an emulator, not the real device, some wrappers with `OkHTTP`, can't launch properly

```
    @Test
    public void calculator() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "6PM0116B24000188");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".Calculator");
        AndroidDriver dr = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.43.242:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
```

Test should run and Calculator app open.
but got the error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
     org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/ApacheHttpClient$Factory
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:55)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
    at CallingNumberTest.calculator(CallingNumberTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by updating the java-client to the 6.1.o version.